# This keyword in React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the below code,i am getting an error handleClick is not defined. I tried using something like onClick={this.handleClick} but it's not working. How do I access handleClick function for the onClick event of the Lik given below

```
    const VerifyOTP = ({ UserProfile }) => {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState();
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(null);
    const [input, setInput] = useState(null);

    handleClick = () => {
        enableOTPBox(false);
    };

    let displaySendOTPAgain = () => {
        setDisplay(
            <Link href="#">
                <a
                    onClick={handleClick} //Error -Handle click method is not defined
                    style={{
                        color: '#0000EE',
                    }}>
                    Resend OTP Again
                </a>
            </Link>
        );
    };
    
    enableOTPBox = (input) => {
        //code
    };

   
    return (
        <div className="row">            
            <div className="col-sm-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                    {input} {display}
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    );
};

export default VerifyOTP;
```

Comment: You're not declaring your variables `handleClick` and `enableOTPBox`, which means the code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). I strongly recommend using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so that's the error it always should have been in the language. It's not clear how that would cause the error you've described, though.

Comment: *"This keyword in React function component"* Just for the avoidance of doubt: You almost never use `this` in a function component.

Comment: The alternative is to use explicit function declarations rather than function expressions, and this problem wouldn't arise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `handleClick` with `const`:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    enableOTPBox(false);
};
```

Comment: You don't **have** to, but you really should, or you get what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). But I can't see how that would result in the described symptom.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `this` keyword in functional based components.
it's better to write functions like below.

Traditional way

```
function handleClick () {
  enableOTPBox(false);
};
```

or

arrow function

```
const handleClick = () =>{
  enableOTPBox(false);
};
```

or

Expression function

```
let handleClick = function handleClick(){
   enableOTPBox(false);
};
```